# How do I send an input thru socket?

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I wanted to make a pysocket-based messenger and everything was alright before I tried my code: it shows this error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. What sould I do?
BTW, here's the code:

```py
# Client
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
sock.send('hi')

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print(data)
```

```py
# Server
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
sock.send(input(MSG: )) #Something wrong here...

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
sock.send('hi'.encode())
```

BTW: Your server and your client are the same???

Comment: Wait... I MESSED UP THE CODES. Anyway, already did it. Ty.